# Meaning of ^ in git describe command

Tags: git, describe

I'm reading through documentation about `git describe` command. Here https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe

Under EXAMPLES I see a command

```
$ git describe --all --abbrev=4 v1.0.5^2
```

I was wondering what is the meaning of `^` in `v1.0.5^2` and what is the meaning of `v1.0.5^2`.

Thanks

Comment: Technically, this is unrelated to `git describe` itself: the hat-suffix (or hat-and-number suffix) is generic across most Git commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

^2 means the second parent. In this case the second parent of v1.0.5. If you write v1.0.5^, it would mean it's the first parent.